# How to write a file in java 7 with fewer bytes than myByteArray.length

Tags: file, arrays, java-7

Java 7 has a new `nio.file` package for writing files more efficiently

A brief look at the java tutorial shows that this is the normal way to write a new file. Simple enough.

```
Files.write(Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options)
```

My only quip is that I've got a byte[] of length 1000 and only want to write say 800 bytes of that array.  I don't have to copy the array do I?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618396/in-java-is-where-a-way-to-create-a-subarray-that-will-point-to-a-portion-of-a-b